# string comparison in batch file not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

I have this code:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

SET OutofService=Weblog_Doc(file:///C:/Bla/BlaKon.htm?send=2000)


REM - Declare and set the Array

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (C:\Folder1\log.dat) DO (
    SET /a c+=1
    SET x[!c!]=%%a          
)   

REM - Read Array from end to start
FOR /l %%I IN (!c! -1 1) DO (                   

    SET _result=!x[%%I]:~-47%!      

    ECHO !_result!
    ECHO !OutofService!

    IF "!_result!"=="!OutofService!" (              
        ECHO yahooo!                
    )           
)
```

The string in file `log.dat` is as follows:

```
09/17/15 15:18:52:577 Container:
Weblog_Doc(file:///C:/Bla/BlaKon.htm?send=2000)
```

My `ECHO` statement is outputting the result:

```
Weblog_Doc(file:///C:/Bla/BlaKon.htm?send=2000)
Weblog_Doc(file:///C:/Bla/BlaKon.htm?send=2000)
```

The `if` statement is returning `false` and not outputting `yahooo!` as it should, given the fact that these two strings should be equal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SET _result=!x[%%I]:~-47%!` - why is this percentage after the 47?

Comment: @npocmaka I get the same result with or without it, I guess it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Change your ECHO commands to `echo !_result!XXX` and `echo !OutofService!XXX` and you will see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET x[!c!]=%%a          
              ^^^^^^^^^^ Spaces included in value
....
SET _result=!x[%%I]:~-47%!      
                          ^^^^^^ Spaces included in value
```

Try with (percent sign in the third line is not needed)

```
SET "OutofService=Weblog_Doc(file:///C:/Bla/BlaKon.htm?send=2000)"
....
SET "x[!c!]=%%a"
....
SET "_result=!x[%%I]:~-47!"
```

This way, while the assignment operation is quoted, the quotes are not included in the value, nor the ending spaces if present.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I still get the same output. IF statement is still returning false.

Comment: This is easy to reproduce, is this SET "_result=!x[%%I]:~-47!" working for you?

Comment: @codemonkey, sorry, I forget to include the first assignment in the answer.

Comment: When I add SET "x[!c!]=%%a" statement is outputting the result                        :  WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(file:///C:/WebPages/OutofService.htm?message=2000)
WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(file:///C:/WebPages/OutofService.htm?message=2000)

Comment: It adds a colon to the string, IF statement is still returning false.